# Sum time output from processes (bash)

Tags: bash, time

I've made an script which measure the time of some processes. This is the  file  that I get:

```
real    0m6.768s
real    0m5.719s
real    0m5.173s
real    0m4.245s
real    0m5.257s
real    0m5.479s
real    0m6.446s
real    0m5.418s
real    0m5.654s
```

The command I use to get the time is this one:

```
{ time my-command } |& grep real >> times.txt
```

What I need is to sum all this times and get as a result how many (hours if applies) minutes and seconds using a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bash`, then if PAGER is less `/ time`.

> ```
>   If the time reserved word precedes a pipeline, the elapsed as well as user and system time consumed by its  exe-
>   cution  are reported when the pipeline terminates.  The -p option changes the output format to that specified by
>   POSIX.  The TIMEFORMAT variable may be set to a format string that specifies how the timing  information  should
>    be displayed; see the description of TIMEFORMAT under Shell Variables below.
> ```

then `/TIMEFORMAT`

> ```
>          The  optional  l  specifies  a  longer  format, including minutes, of the form MMmSS.FFs.  The value of p
>          determines whether or not the fraction is included.
>
>
>          If this variable is not set, bash acts as if it had the value  $'\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys%3lS'.   If
>          the  value  is  null,  no  timing  information is displayed.  A trailing newline is added when the format
>          string is displayed.
> ```

If it can be changed to something like

```
TIMEFORMAT=$'\nreal\t%3R'
```

without the `l`, it may be easier to sum.

Note also format may depend on locale `LANG`:

compare

```
(LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8; time sleep 1)
```

and

```
(LANG=C; time sleep 1)
```

In that case the sum can be done with an external tool like `awk`

```
awk '/^real/ {sum+=$2} END{print sum} ' times.txt
```

or perl

```
perl -aln -e '$sum+=$F[1] if /^real/; END{print $sum}' times.txt
```

Comment: So, you say that I have to regenerate the times in order to change the TIMEFORMAT? is there any way to do it? I mean, thank you for your response I checked it out and work perfectly. I just want to make sure that there is other way.

Comment: i didn't mean you need but if you can it's easier otherwise you just have to convert min to seconds, sum and then convert or not to min,sec

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output to this command

```
grep real | awk '{ gsub("m","*60+",$2); gsub("s","+",$2); printf("%s",$2); } END { printf("0\n"); }' | bc
```

This should work if you have generated the output using built-in time command. The output is in seconds.